# Conversão de ponteiros em C para assembly

Tags: c, ponteiro, assembly

Boa tarde, vou ter teste de assembly e tenho uma dúvida que é sobre ponteiros em assembly. 
Estou a tentar fazer um exercício mas não o consigo resolver.
"Considere as declarações em C:

```
int x=100, y=200;
int far *ptx;
int far *pty;
```

supondo que foram já executadas as instruções:

```
ptx=&x;
pty=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

a minha dúvida está em como codificar as seguintes alíneas em assembly:

a) `ptx=pty`

b)`*ptx=*pty`

Comment: "int far *" não existe mais, a não ser que você esteja programando para MS-DOS...

Comment: usamos o dosbox para programar, com o turboC

Comment: use o debugger para ver as instruções assembly, ou então na compilação use a opção (que não sei qual é) para gerar uma listagem assembly...não me lembro dos detalhes, mas sei que as duas coisas acima são possíveis

Comment: o problema e que isto é um exercício de teste. Eu vou fazer frequência e precisava de saber isto, mas não tenho como saber

Comment: tenho de fazer esse código por escrito, e não no computador

Comment: Qual arquitetura estão usando? x86 ou MIPS?

Comment: usamos assembly do processador 8086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo programação em "modo real" para 8086, então vamos usar o registrador de uso geral AX (16 bits), o registrador de uso geral e de índice BX (16 bits), e o registrador de segmento ES (16 bits).
PS. ES = "extra segment"

```
int x=100, y=200;
int far *ptx;
int far *pty;
```

supondo que foram já executadas as instruções:

```
ptx = &x;
pty = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

a minha dúvida está em como codificar as seguintes alíneas em assembly:

```
isso aqui parece razoavelmente fácil: cada ponteiro far é composto por 2 bytes de
segmento e dois bytes de offset
a) ptx = pty

    ; offset
    MOV AX, word ptr pty
    MOV word ptr ptx, AX

    ; segmento
    MOV AX, word ptr pty+2
    MOV word ptr ptx+2, AX

aqui tem que usar o registrador ES
b) *ptx = *pty 

    ; carrega pty em ES:BX
    LES BX, pty

    ; carrega *pty em AX
    MOV AX, word ptr ES:[BX]

    ; carrega ptx em ES:BX
    LES BX, ptx

    ; salva AX em *ptx
    MOV word ptr ES:[BX], AX
```

É possível ter algum probleminha de sintaxe, teríamos que rodar o MASM 17 bits para verificar isso, mas no geral é isso aí.

Comment: muito muito obrigado pela ajuda